# React table slow loading when displaying img rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, loadimage

I am new to React. I am just trying to build a table of data coming from an API which I got it fetching. But now I want to render the data into a table.

My issue is that one of the columns is a logo that comes from a URL `index.php?Action=GetLogo&id=51`. The number of results is more than 300. Even though I am already using pagination the table rendering is slow, particularly the `logo` column. All the data gets loaded, but I can see each logo being rendered row by row, giving the user a slow experience.

Is there any way how React can approach to solve this issue? Someone please point me in the right direction how to tackle this.

Thanks everyone.

**Update**
Someone has advised me to use a sync/await function to load the images. Then I am updating the code. However my main issue is still with me: loading the data particularly the logo column. All the data gets rendered, but not the logo column, then each logo starts to render one by one looking very slow. I thought the `async/await` function would alleviate that.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import FormData from 'form-data';

    class FilterableSupplierTable extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                suppliers: []
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('AjaxMethodName', 'GetSuppliers');
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': '*/*'
                },
                body: formData
            };
            fetch(`?Model=route_to_controller`, options)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    this.setState({ suppliers: JSON.parse(data.response_data) })
                });
        }

        async getLogos(suppliers) {
            return await Promise.all(
                suppliers.map(async supplier => {
                    supplier.new_logo = !!supplier.has_logo ?
                        <img style={{maxWidth: "100px"}} src={supplier.logo} alt={supplier.supplier_id} /> :
                        <i className="icon icon-warning no_logo">&nbsp;No Logo</i>;
                    return supplier;
                });
            );
        }

        render() {
            const rows = [];
            const suppliers = this.state.suppliers;
            this.getLogos(suppliers)
                .then(results => {
                    results.map(supplier => {
                        rows.push(
                            <tr>
                                {/* supplier.logo is index.php?Action=GetLogo&id=51, etc */}
                                <td><img src={supplier.new_logo} /></td>
                                <td>{supplier.name}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    });
                });

            return (
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colSpan="4">Suppliers</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Logo</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
                </table>
            );
        }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
        <FilterableSupplierTable />,
        document.getElementById('suppliers_list')
    );
```

Comment: sometimes the size of the images can increase load time in dev enviroment are you certain the images are web optimized?

Comment: 'Lagging' can mean more things. Try using `await` or a `Suspense` block

Comment: @AdrianPascu I will check that thanks I have also updated the title.

Comment: Could it be a case where these images are extremely 'heavy'? High resolution and  also not optimized which can lead to large filesizes to render in the table component?

Comment: @AdrianPascu. Can you give me an example how can I use those blocks?

Comment: Async/Await is a JS feature to await the response o a promise. You should read on how to use it. The official MDN doc is pretty good. As for the Suspense block, here is a pretty good example https://blog.logrocket.com/react-suspense-for-data-fetching/ . It uses hooks instead of class based components, but hooks are really not hard to understand and are very well documented in the react docs. Everything can be mapped to class components if you don't want to switch to hooks

Comment: Why do you use `async` inside `getLogos`? There's nothing asynchronous inside that `map` loop

Comment: @GalAbra Thanks, yes I removed the `async` and now my array looks better (I'll update my question). However, my main issue is still with me: loading the data particularly the logo column. All the data gets rendered, but not the logo column, then each logo starts to render one by one looking very slow. I thought the `async/await` function would alleviate that.

Comment: @ivantxo The alternative would be to wait until all logos are loaded, which will result in a blank column for a longer time period. Is that what you want?

Comment: @GalAbra. No, I would like to wait and load the logos, don't display anything, maybe just a spinning loading wheel. Then, when all the logos have loaded, render everything. Is this possible? Is the best thing to do in these cases?

Comment: @GalAbra sorry man my array still looks empty. So, nothing gets rendered. I am printing this array into the console and when I expand it, it has all the rows, but when collapsed seems empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue can be solved with a component that updates a "global loading state".

Only after *all* images have updated that they finished loading, they become visible together:

```
function MyImage(props) {
  const onLoad = () => {
    props.onLoad();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {props.isCurrentlyLoading && <div>Loading</div>}
      <img
        src={props.src}
        onLoad={onLoad}
        style={
          props.isCurrentlyLoading
            ? { width: "0", height: "0" } // You can also use opacity, etc.
            : { width: 100, height: 100 }
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function ImagesBatch() {
  const [loadedImagesCounter, setLoadedImagesCounter] = useState(0);
  const [isAllLoaded, setIsAllLoaded] = useState(false);

  const updateLoading = () => {
    if (loadedImagesCounter + 1 === imagesUrls.length) {
      setIsAllLoaded(true);
    }
    setLoadedImagesCounter(prev => prev + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {imagesUrls.map((url, index) => {
        return (
          <MyImage
            key={url}
            src={url}
            index={index + 1}
            isCurrentlyLoading={!isAllLoaded}
            onLoad={updateLoading}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check the full code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loading-all-images-synchronously-pt318?file=/src/App.js) (preferably with an open console), where I used an arbitrary ~6MB image, as an example.

Comment: I am checking thank you. I won't even need my `getLogos` (async/await) function if I use yours?
My images are on the KBs :p

Comment: @ivantxo That's right. You only need to filter your clients array, to make sure you only count those with a valid image url

Comment: How can I have one single `Loading` message for all the elements instead of a `Loading` message for each image?

Comment: Yes, just remove it from `MyImage` and add in `ImagesBatch`

Comment: I have a long way to go into React... Thanks @GalAbra

Answer (score 1):

I think you got your issues resolved. But, apart from that I suggest you checkout React Virtualized, https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Hope this helps some day.